# deepcopy in IronPython

Tags: .net, ironpython, deep-copy

I want to do a deepcopy in IronPython, but when I write

```
import copy
```

I get `no module named copy`.

> How do I deepcopy in IronPython?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [IronPython version 2.6.1](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/36280), and select the **standard library option** in the installer.
An example from my installation:

```
IronPython 2.6.1 (2.6.10920.0) on .NET 2.0.50727.4927
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import copy
>>> help(copy.deepcopy)
Help on function deepcopy in module copy:

deepcopy(x, memo=None, _nil=[])
    Deep copy operation on arbitrary Python objects.

    See the module's __doc__ string for more info.

>>> copy.deepcopy(range(5))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```